# Jaxb: namespace unmarshalling issue

Tags: java, xml, spring, jaxb

all, I have a package full of Beans generated from `xsd` with `Jaxb`.
I want to use some of them into another Bean to marshal/unmarshal an XML like this:

```
<WrongDocument>
    <test>test label</test>
    <CBISDDReqLogMsg xmlns="urn:CBI:xsd:CBISDDReqLogMsg.00.01.00">
        <GrpHdr>
          ....
        </GrpHdr>
        <PmtInf>
        </PmtInf>
    </CBISDDReqLogMsg>
</WrongDocument>
```

the root Bean is

```
@XmlRootElement(name="WrongDocument")
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
  "test",
  "CBISDDReqLogMsg"
})
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class WrongDocumentDTO implements Serializable {

 private static final long serialVersionUID = 8545918230166653233L;

 @XmlElement(required = true, type = String.class, nillable = true)
    protected String test;

 @XmlElement(required = true)
 protected CBISDDReqLogMsg000100 CBISDDReqLogMsg;

 ....

}
```

and the `CBISDDReqLogMsg000100` is

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "CBISDDReqLogMsg.00.01.00", propOrder = {
    "grpHdr",
    "pmtInf"
})
public class CBISDDReqLogMsg000100
    implements Serializable
{

    private final static long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @XmlElement(name = "GrpHdr", required = true)
    protected CBIGroupHeader2 grpHdr;
    @XmlElement(name = "PmtInf", required = true)
    protected List<PaymentInstructionInformation2> pmtInf;

    ....

}
```

For `CBISDDReqLogMsg000100` namespace is defined with `package-info` file.

This is the code for unmarshalling:

```
jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(WrongDocumentDTO.class);
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
WrongDocumentDTO wrongDocumentDTO = unmarshaller.unmarshal(source, WrongDocumentDTO.class).getValue();
```

Unfortunately, inside my `wrongDocumentDTO` i have test field populated with the right value, however `CBISDDReqLogMsg` is null.

How can i resolve this issue?

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to specify the [namespace](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElement.html#namespace()) specifically on the `element` if it is not default for the whole `package`.

```
@XmlElement(required = true, namespace = "urn:CBI:xsd:CBISDDReqLogMsg.00.01.00")
protected CBISDDReqLogMsg000100 CBISDDReqLogMsg;
```

Comment: It's work!

I made this test before posting here....using the wrong namespace.

thank you